# Boxdecoration fit parent height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to make a `container` with `background image` and background color in the bottom 30 pixels, but I need the layout to look like this:

[image]

```
SizedBox(
            height: 540,
            child: Container(
              width: 392.7,
              height: 510,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(25)),
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: Image.network(
                      'https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/8258557/thumb/1.jpg',
                    ).image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your ui I think u have to use stack instead of column use stack and it will provide your desire output

Here is code example:-

```
SizedBox(
      height: 540,
      child: Stack(
        children: [ 
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image:

                  /// your image
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                )),
          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                height: 30,
                // set color and border radius as u need 
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Column` to and use another `Container` or `Material`... widget to provide extra 30px border.

```dart
  SizedBox(
              height: 540,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 392.7,
                    height: 510,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(25)),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: Image.network(
                            'https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/8258557/thumb/1.jpg',
                          ).image,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    height: 30.0,
                    width: 392.7,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
```

But For background cases you can use `Stack` for it.

```dart
  SizedBox(
              height: 540,
              width: 392.7,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 392.7,
                    height: 510,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(25)),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: Image.network(
                            'https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/8258557/thumb/1.jpg',
                          ).image,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

More about [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below and let me know if change required.

```
SizedBox(
      height: 540,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg",
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            )),
          )),
          Container(
            height: 30,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```